# carry over user entered carriage returns from message box and sent in email

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email

I have a working HTML email sender using c#, but it doesn't carry over the carriage returns entered by the user in the message field

For the message field I have:

`<asp:TextBox ID="tbMessage" runat="server" MaxLength="255" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="20" rows="5" Width="155px"  CssClass="share_input"  />`

and inserted in the HTML email to be sent I have:
`"+ tbMessage.Text.ToString() +"`

but it's not showing the user entered carriage returns in the emailed message area.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What encoding are you using when sending the e-mails?

Comment: private void SendNewsletterLink()
    {

Comment: @AaronLS: please see [“That's not what the comments are for”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213963/thats-not-what-the-comments-are-for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending HTML email, then you need to convert new line characters (CR/LF) into HTML line break tags; e.g. `<br />`

```
var htmlEmail = tbMessage.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Concat(Environment.NewLine,"<br />"));
```

This will keep the newline chars and then append `<br />` tags after it. HTML email readers should render new lines properly with the added `<br />`.

Comment: I think Environment.NewLine is wrong in this case, because the newlines will use whatever character the CLIENT browser's textbox uses, NOT the SERVER.  It may work, but only by concidence when the server and browser both use the same newline.  Otherwise this is correct.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I just entered
"+ tbMessage.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Concat(Environment.NewLine,"<br />")) +"

Comment: @AaronLS, yes you are correct. My example here is just to show that newline chars need conversion to HTML line breaks for it to be rendered properly. For full compatibility, yes, one needs to consider non-windows OS client where it will just be CR without LF for new line.